# Why JQuery dialog isn't opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a dialog when enter is pressed. But that isn't opening dialog just hiding text.
Can someone explain why?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<script>

    $(document).keydown(function(mykey2){
        if(mykey2.which == 13){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        }
    });

   
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I didn't understang what is wrong.

Comment: try adding `http:` before the `//code..`s?

Comment: I think it is a version problem, works **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wjgahkLk/1/)** but not with your version **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wjgahkLk/2/)**

Comment: Oh yeah that is true too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to cancel the enter key press.

```js
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```